# Every planar graph $G$ is $5$-colorable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

In the proof of $5$-colorable planar graph $G$.

We have the base case $n\le5$ then the induction case for $n+1\ge6$. We want to show that $G$ is $5$-colorable. I will not detail the proof for base case.

Induction hypothesis: Let us assume that every simple, planar graph on $n$ vertices where $n\ge5$ is $5$-colorable.

In one case out of many cases that follows from the induction hypothesis, we might have vertex $u$ where all of its 5 neighbors take different colors, say $(1,2,3,4,5)$. For this particular case that I am asking about, we might consider the subgraph $H$ of $G$ consisting vertices colored either 1 and 3 and all edges between these vertices (subgraph spanned by these vertices) given that we have vertices $(a,b,c,d,e)$ colored $(1,2,3,4,5)$ respectively. Vertices $a$ and $c$ are in $H$ because they get colored $1$ and $3$.

My problem: Since $H$ is $2$-colorable, then it's bipartite. In the proof, it's mentioned that if $H$ has several components and $a$ and $c$ lie in different components, then swap the color of vertices in the component containing $a$. This gives another $5$-coloring of $G-u$ in which the color of $a$ switch to 3 but the color of $c$ remain 3, but now we can color $u$ with 1 to get a $5$-coloring of $G$ (if we get lucky). Can you please clarify my problem in another words as I don't understand how $a$ and $c$ lie in different components while we choose them to be in a bipartite graph with 2 colors?

Comment: You might need to reproduce the proof, to provide complete context. Without knowing the exact details, it seems like you are assuming "if H has several components and a and c lie in different components", but then asking how we can make such an assumption. I'm guessing that the proof is splitting into several cases, of which one of them is "H has several components and a and c lie in different components".

Comment: @CalvinLin, we have the base case, induction case for $n+1\ge6$

Comment: Are you having difficulty seeing that there can exist a bipartite graph with more than one connected component?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, this is how the Doctor explained it, so yes it confuses me to see what he mean by different components given we have on bipartite graph? Another claim the Doctor said, let us say we draw a cycle from $1$ to $3$, then $b$ will be separated from $d$ in case both are connected to vertex $u$, and we thus $b$ has to be in a different component given that all vertices $(a,b,c,d,e)$ are connected to $u$ and $u$ is in the center like a star. Even in the former case, I don't get why we got a different component as well?

Comment: What is your definition of bipartite?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, A graph $G$ is bipartite if we can partition the vertices into two sets $X$ and $Y$ such that every edge of $G$ has exactly one endpoint in $X$ and another endpoint in $Y$.

Comment: So if you have two bipartite graphs, one with vertices in sets $X_1$ and $Y_1$, the other in sets $X_2$ and $Y_2$, then you can combine them into a single bipartite graph with vertex sets $X_1\cup X_2$ and $Y_1\cup Y_2$. This gives you a bipartite graph with (at least) two components. Note that you can also put them together with vertex sets $X_1\cup Y_2$ and $Y_1\cup X_2$. This is essentially swapping the two colours in one of the compnents.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, Thank you. You mentioned you can combine the two into a single bipartite graph, so you have at least 2 components, so how we can two components if the combination is one bipartite graph with one component? Why you said 2 components or more?

Comment: The combination of two bipartite graphs, each with one component, gives you one bipartite graph with two components. An example of such a graph is the graph with 4 vertices $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and two edges $(a,b),(c.d)$. It is bipartite with the sets $X=\{a,c\}$ and $Y=\{b,d\}$, but it obviously has two components ($\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis. Thanks. So every if we have ${a,c,b,d,e}$ and 3 edges $(a,b), (a,d), (c,e)$, then we would have two components $({(a,b), (a,d)},{c,e})$?